# How to send transactions on mobile in a Next.js app using Rainbowkit

Tags: nextjs, rainbowkit

I have a nextjs app installed with rainbowkit and connecting/sending tx's works fine on desktop. However, on mobile I'm able to connect through metamask but fail when sending a transaction.

Any ideas of where I can debug this?